# Scroll the mouse changes the value of my select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

I'm having problems with mouse scroll in some browsers, if the user goes up or down within my website affects selects several values that I have. This happens in all browsers and I figured there was a way through by javascript could cancel the event or to cancel the values are changed.

Comment: Please post some code, we can't figure out what you're trying to achiev without some code!

Comment: Share some code. Do you have an event listener attached to the scroll event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trigger the `blur` event on `select`:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).blur();


    // OR
    $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/blur/